# How do I solve this Lavalink related error?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

so I have created a music bot recently using node.js and I am using Lavalink to play and manage its music streams. When I ran my code everything went pretty well and thankfully it's running efficiently. But there's a small problem. Whenever I run my code, this error pops up every time:

> Lavalink: Node Main had an error: Unexpected op "ready" with data: [object Object]

(FYI- I hosted my bot on Replit).

How do I handle this error?

I have tried using a different lavalink server but this error keeps showing up all the time. I am not a professional at node.js so I am unable to understand the error, so please help me.

Comment: You are not likely to get a good response with this question. Create the simplest, shortest code example that reproduces the problem. Take a look at [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code, because update 3.5 this problem is coming...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).